# jQuery Validation plugin. Two custom rules not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation engine and I have two custom rules that I need to use for one field. I've tried both of them one by one, they work fine. How do I attach both?

```
class="validate[required,custom[OFS, onlyLattinLetters], maxSize[140]]"
```

or

```
class="validate[required,custom[OFS], custom[onlyLattinLetters], maxSize[140]]"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: you can use both of them seprated by comma.

Comment: have you tried moving from inline html to the validate({ options )} javascript?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: isn't that exactly what he's already showing us?

Comment: @Sparky672 yes, it is, and it doesn't work. Only the first one written does

Comment: **OP:** _"it doesn't work. Only the first one written does "_ ~ Alex, your question is confusing then.  If your first example works (seems to already contain both rules), then what is the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I mean in this case custom[OFS, onlyLattinLetters] only OFS works. But in this custom[onlyLattinLetters, OFC]  onlyLattinLetters does

Comment: Because, AFAIK, your syntax is wrong.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inline classes, have you tried declaring them within the plugin initialization function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            myField: { 
                required: true,
                OFS: true,
                onlyLattinLetters: true,
                maxSize: 140
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**:

I would recommend totally avoiding inline code; I think it's more difficult to maintain, makes your HTML verbose, and it mingles functionality with your presentation styles.

I also removed my example below ([see edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13160319/revisions)), which I found in the jQuery discussion forum, since I cannot find any official documentation on proper syntax and usage.

Answer (score -2):

If you must use inline, use the Add method to create your two custom rules, I'll do one to show

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("onlyLattinLetters", function(value, element) {
 return this.optional(element) || \p{IsBasicLatin}.test(value); 
 // or replace before .test() whatever your regex is 
 }, "Only in Latin numbers please");
```

then you could use your validation call as such, removing the custom[] from  the inline

```
 class="validate[required, OFS, onlyLattinLetters, maxSize[140]]"
```

Truely the better method would be Sparky672's validate() plugin initialization but if you must use inline the above works

Comment: Can you kindly point to any official Validation Plugin documentation that shows proper syntax and usage of inline rules?  I'm finding examples online using braces `{}` and yet others using brackets `[]`.

Comment: i don't see any to be honest...typically multiple rules use the validate() initialization setting rules for fields, i see many using {} or [] in stackoverflow for inline, i think [] may be the correct usage but i cannot confirm or deny such